# Is it possible to change the order DrRacket/Scheme search/reference the library?

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I follow the instructions at 3.3.3 of SICP to create a table.

Here is `code_0.scm`:

```
;code_0.scm
#lang scheme
(require rnrs/base-6)
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)

(define nil '())

(define (make-table)
  (list '*table*))

(define (assoc key records)
  (cond ((null? records)
         false)
        ((equal? key (caar records))
         (car records))
        (else
         (assoc key (cdr records)))))

(define (insert! key value table)
  (let ((record (assoc key (cdr table))))
    (if record
        (set-cdr! record value)
        (set-cdr! table
                  (cons (cons key value)
                        (cdr table)))))
  'OK)

(define (lookup key table)
  (let ((record (assoc key (cdr table))))
    (if record
        (cdr record)
        false)))


(define table (make-table))

(insert! 0 0 table)
(insert! 1 1 table)
(insert! 2 2 table)
```

`code_0.scm` is working well, but not after becoming the external reference file of `code_1.scm`:

;I delete the `#lang scheme` at `code_0.scm` at this moment

```
;code_1.scm
#lang scheme/load
(load "code_0.scm")

(define table-0 (make-table))
(insert! 0 0 table-0)
(insert! 1 1 table-0)
(insert! 2 2 table-0)
```

error shows in DrRacket:

> assoc: not a proper list: {{0 . 0}}

According to [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602788/not-a-proper-list-error-in-drracket-writing-scheme) I pulled up, this happened because the "assoc" function had already defined in the Scheme library(or the DrRacket library?) that the compiler choose to link the standard/system one prior than mine.

So, is it possible to change the order DrRacket/Scheme search/reference the library?

If its a yes, how?

If its a no, is this a defect about the compiler or the language?

Is there another way to avoid this besides implementing it right in the "main" file if I have to build a name-duplicate function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a direct answer for your problem, but a description of the
mess you've gotten yourself into which eventually got to that problem,
and will lead to other problems too.

I'll try to first explain how Racket evaluates a module very briefly,
since it'll be relevant to understanding the mess.  It looks like you're
trying to use "just scheme" so you're probably not too interested in
this, but you should still read it to understand the problems you're in.
(Even if you solved that particular one.)

In the usual case of `.rkt` files each file is evaluated in its own
namespace, which is populated by bindings from (1) the `#lang` that you
specify, and (2) various libraries (= other modules) that you `require`.
So when you have

```
#lang foo
(require bar)
```

you start from a fresh namespace, grab all of the bindings from `foo`
into this namespace, and then you add the bindings from `bar`.  In case
of clashes, the `require` bindings will shadow ones from the language,
so if both of them provided some function `f`, the name that your code
will use will be the one from `bar`.  If you require more than one
library:

```
#lang foo
(require bar baz)
```

and both `bar` and `baz` provide `f`, then you'll get an error *if*
these are different `f`s.  This can happen if, for example, `bar`
provides the builtin `cons` and `baz` provides a `cons` that creates
mutable pairs (ie, provides the builtin `mcons` as `cons`).  You will
*not* get an error if both of them provide the same `f` though.

Again, note that this is different from the "initial bindings" which is
what you get from the `#lang` -- a latter `require` will just shadow
them if the same name is used.  The reason for the `#lang` bindings
treated differently is that they provide some basic bindings that the
code uses at a fundamental level.  For example, the language bindings
will get you the `require` that you use later on.  Another example is a
`#%module-begin` macro that wraps the whole module body -- a tool that
can be used to transform all expressions into something else, for
example, this is how toplevel expressions in the `racket` language get
their value printed.

Roughly speaking, libraries (= modules) in racket are split into
language modules and library modules.  This is not something that is
formal since both are implemented in the same way: modules that provide
stuff.  The difference is in the kind of stuff that they provide, where
language modules will usually provide lots of bindings, include basic
ones like `require` and `#%module-begin`, and things that you expect
from a lispish language like `define`, `if`, `cond`, `+`, `cons`, etc.

In the usual case, therefore, you don't run into problems of name
clashes too much since libraries try to avoid common names.  But if you
try to `require` a language module as if its a library, you very quickly
run into such problems since language modules tend to provide lots of
names, including those very common names like the ones I listed above.

Now you can see how this is a problem in your `code0.scm`:

```
#lang scheme
(require rnrs/base-6)
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
```

what this does is use the `scheme` bindings first.  This `scheme`
language is *not* standard scheme -- it's the precursor to the `racket`
language, dating to before the name change when Racket was known as PLT
Scheme, and therefore `scheme` was intended to be "the scheme dialect
that PLT Scheme uses by default".  Among other things, it has immutable
pairs, same as the ones you get in `#lang racket` files.

But later on you pile up most of the `rnrs` bindings -- and those use
*mutable* pairs, which are, as you've discovered, a different type.
You're requiring a module that is usually used as a language, so *most*
of the bindings you use will work fine, but sooner or later you'll run
into a binding from `scheme` that is not shadowed by one from `rnrs`,
and if it's something that has to do with pairs, you'll get problems.

So the conclusion here is to avoid mixing up two languages like this:
either stick to `#lang scheme` or to `#lang r6rs`.  In the former case,
you can just as well switch to `#lang racket`, and use the usual racket
libraries, and in the latter case you should be careful and try to avoid
importing racket libraries that expect immutable pairs (and more).
Alternatively, if your goal is to do some SICP, then use [the SICP
language](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/) that Neil Van Dyke
wrote.

But you have more problems, still.  In your `code_1.scm` you're using
`scheme/load` as the language, and that's something that might make it
possible to do what you're trying to do -- but it brings with it a whole
pile of other problems.  I you look up the documentation for
`scheme/load` (which will send you to the docs for `racket/load`, the
more modern name), you'll see some stuff about `eval` and `load`.  This
is because at some point people wanted to be able to write a single file
that has several modules in it, but that was not possible.  (Now it is,
and you get submodules -- but `racket/load` is still kept around.)
`scheme/load` was implemented to address this: using it is as if you're
entering expressions in a single REPL, so you can define a bunch of
modules and use them.  But it's an odd language because of this, and if
you don't want that particular feature, you should avoid it.

The `load` in the name is something that should have actually been
something that discourages people from using it...  The thing is that
`load` is an old and primitive tool for structuring code, which was the
only available thing in the standard language up to R5RS.  The thing
that it does is (again, this is a rough description) `read` expressions
from a file and `eval`uate them.  The problem is that you get a single
namespace for everything, and worse, each definition can actually be a
mutation of a previous definition if one existed.  This means that even
simple definitions like

```
(define (add1 x) (+ 1 x))
```

are not safe, since a later `load` of a file can redefine `+` in a way
that breaks this definition.  In short, this is very much a mess in a
world where many libraries provide you with the same names but with
different semantics.  IOW, it's usually a mess in Racket.  Racket (and
later, R6RS) uses modules in a way that sorts the whole thing out in a
much better way -- there's no single namespace and mutation, just names
that are provided from closed modules.  Actualy, the mutation thing is
still there, but it is more restricted in the damage you can get (it's
used only in the REPL); and `load` is there too, together with `eval`,
and they are generally avoided as tools to organize source files.

Using `load` also explains why you had to remove the `#lang` line when
you've used it -- when you `load` a file with a module definition, you
get just *that* definition -- the module's.  To actually use the things
that the module provides, you'd also need to add a `(require 'code_0)`.
Yet another thing is that dropping the `#lang` line is usually a
disaster since you're left without the necessary bindings for any
reasonable piece of code -- but in your case, you `require`d a whole
language later on, which is how things continued to work, only with
subtle differences.

So the second highlevel conclusion is to avoid `load` -- it's a bad
tool.  Also, avoid the `scheme/load` or `racket/load` languages unless
you really know what they're doing and need that functionality.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It may take some time for me to understand `language modules` and  library modules `.

Comment: At the end did you just describe the `load` is dirty but necessary?

Comment: No, it's not necessary, and it's hardly ever used in Racket code.  I've edited it to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see `assoc: not a proper list: {{0 . 0}}` needs an explanation.

In the Racket language you can create immutable pairs with `cons` and mutable pairs with `mcons`. Normally in the Scheme language `cons` also creates immutable pairs - but since you have the lines

```
(require rnrs/base-6)
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
```

all the standard list functions are replaced with ones that create mutable ones.

Note that mutable and immutable pairs are two totally separate datatypes - even though they are both called pairs.

Somewhere in the system there are defined primitives, say, `prim-mcons` and `prim-icons` that create mutable and immutable pairs. The `#lang scheme` binds `cons` to 
`prim-mcons` and `#lang racket` binds `cons` to `prim-icons`.

This has an effect on all standard functions working on lists. The `assoc` from `rnrs/mutable-pairs-6`  expects a list made of mutable pairs, and the Racket `assoc` expects a list made of immutable pairs. Hence the error.

How can one spot this? In the Racket language where you can use both `mcons` and `cons` the standard list operations creates lists with immutable pairs and the printer prints them using `(...)`. Mutable pairs are printed with curly braces `{...}`.

The error

```
assoc: not a proper list: {{0 . 0}}
```

shows the association lists with curly braces. That means that the association list was created in the Scheme using mutable pairs.

To fix your problem, you need to use the correct `assoc`. You can do that by adding the lines

```
(require rnrs/base-6)
(require rnrs/mutable-pairs-6)
```

to your second file as well.

Note: the `#lang scheme` language isn't one of the RnRS Schemes, but the dialect that Racket used before the project changed name.

Note 2: Why did Racket remove mutability from pairs in the first place? Well, in well-written Scheme code it is rare to see `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` in use. Having the guarantee that a pair is never mutated allows various optimizations that allow most programs to run faster (for one `length` can be implemented to use constant time). The choice was therefore made to make immutable pairs the standard and keep mutable pairs around for the those programs that absolutely need them.

Comment: So kind for your detailed explanation, but your solution (adding 2 `require` line) doesn't work either.  If it works on your machine, either you or me must left out sth. version: DrRacket 6.1.1/OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: By the way, I've solved this problem already. My confused point right now is how could I make my function at prior order of being search/referenced  than the system/standard one in name-duplicate situation.

Comment: @soegaard So every `cons` have a field for properness that gets inherited by the tail at construction?

Comment: @Sylwester Yes. I just checked the source and there is a flag for properness. I thought the length was cached too, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

**I don't get any errors running your file in DrRacket.** The file you `load` is probably the old file from the last question. That is the only logical conclusion since none of the files you list here use `assoc` but the old ones do.

It's not advisable to blend Scheme and Racket. `#lang scheme` (or `#!scheme`) is the old name for what is `#!racket` today and it imports all symbols currently in `#!racket` and your `require` statements is in addition to that.

The libraries under `rnrs` are meant to be used by the R6RS language, thus the first line should be `#!r6rs` and instead of require you use `(import (rnrs base) (rnrs mutable-pairs))`. In R6RS you can import except some symbols. Eg. `(import (except (rnrs base) cons))` does not import `cons` but everything else. I didn't use `assoc` since there is no `assoc` in `(rnrs base)` nor `(rnrs mutable-pairs)` so it was probably from `#!scheme` (`#!racket`)

If you plan to use your dictionary as a library you can make it a R6RS library and import it instead of using `load`.

Also notice that there is a [SICP compatibility language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25096066/1565698) in Racket as well. It's based on `#!r5rs` and most examples from the book works as well!

Comment: I was pasting the wrong code, the improved one. now its the one with problem. I been blending all the scheme liked language (standard). I would try `#!r5rs` but seems it doesn't support REPL?

Comment: @Rahn I get the interactive window working with both `#!r5rs` and `#!r6rs`. The perhaps irritating is that evaluated forms in the definitions windows isn't printed as if the program is running, but evaluation in the interaction window does.

Comment: I am sorry I was wrong again. I was about to say that I cannot get the value showed in the window without a `display`

Comment: @Rahn I previously made a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19624049/1565698) about that. Easiest solution is to use `display` or perhaps wrap top level in a macro like this: `(define-syntax pbegin (syntax-rules () ((_ expr ...) (begin (begin (display expr) (newline)) ...))))`

Comment: Ah, I just check the link. thanks for all of this. So kind of you.